# Dependencies needeed to use only data binding in Aurelia?

Tags: data-binding, aurelia

As part of the architecture team, we are currently discussing about how frontend should be developped. With the huge amount and versatility of the js framework we have decided to stick on standard as much as possible. So we have decided to use ECMA6 script with web component, fetch api for ajax and polyfills. However, we don't have any data binding for the moment. I was looking for a non intrusive framework that will do the job and found Aurelia very interesting. However, some of us are concerned by the relative heavy weight of the lib(270k+60k for system.js) while we only need data-binding. Is there a way to reduce the size of this lib ? I have noticed there is a data-binding library ? Is it possible to only use that library ? If so how ?